# Will element not in DOM but with attached handlers be removerd from browser memory using GC?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, garbage-collection

In order to get image dimensions in my js-script, I create temporary `<img>` element without attaching it to DOM. This is the simplified version of a function I wrote:

```js
function testImage(i) {
    let tester = document.createElement('img');
    tester.onload = function() { console.log(tester.naturalWidth); }
    tester.src = `${i}.jpg`;
}
```

1. `tester` is used only inside function.
2. `tester` is never arrached to DOM.
3. onload function has some actions to do with this `tester`. I wonder if it will interfere with garbage collector.

Let's assume this can be called many many many times. Will those testers consume memory? Or will garbage collector remove them?

**PS:** Console `for (let k=0; k < 1000000000; k++) { testImage(k) }` eats my whole memory.

**PS2:** I know I can write script that will reuse same `<img>` element or elements. But I am curious about first approach.

**UPD:** As @rojo said GC cleans memory, but I did not notice it in my case because:

1. Looks like GC does not clean memory in synchronous loop (at least in browser). The line `for (let k=0; k < (1000*1000); k++) { testImage(k) }` eats a lot of memory, but 1000 repeats of loops with 1000 test executed with `setTimeout` does not consume so much memory. Manual execution of different sized loops shows that memory released after loop is finished.
2. This particular script writes many logs to browser console. If console is open, it consumes more memory to keep logs. When I rewrote tester to prevent logging, memory consumption with opened console decreased, but GC worked the same way.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [Memory Management (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management). I _think_ the variable will get deleted every time.

Comment: "eats my whole memory" but does it actually do garbage collection?

Comment: @JonasWilms I think eating a lot of memory means that garbage is still in memory.

Comment: yes. But it could still be viable for garbage collection, just the GC did not cycle. Most browsers only collect under pressure (when memory is full)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) (scroll down to **Limitation: Circular References**), those variables will be deleted.

All variables created inside of a function will be deleted once the function finishes, with no exceptions.

```
function foo() {
  var a = "data";
  console.log(a); // "data"
} // variable is deleted
console.log(a); // Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Comment: I found nothing about WHEN garbage collection starts. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen it starts when the function finishes. It ends when the variables are deleted.

Comment: have you got any docs that proof that GC starts only after synchronous function ended?

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen it's kind of implied in the docs. Also in [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-in-javascript/) (scroll to Cycles are no longer problem, about halfway down), they say the allocation is reclaimed. Of course, it depends on the speed of the computer, but it should start immediately or within a millisecond or two.

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen Also, you might want to ask the [JS room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript). Just ask if garbage collection starts immediately after a function ends

Comment: usually it does not. Reclaiming unneeded memory is a waste of computing time